# iPhone/iPad In app rating?

Tags: iphone

I have seen that some apps have a option for the user to rate their app from within the app. Anyone here knows how to do that?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote about it in a blog post [here](http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/09/03/Open-Reviews.html). The user will be taken to the App Store app and I don't believe you will be able to do all from within you own app.

This is the gist of it

```
- (IBAction)gotoReviews:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str]; 
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];

    // Here is the app id from itunesconnect
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@289382458", str]; 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
```