# I Want to add Rating Features in my Application What Are the Way To do This?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect, xml-parsing

I Want to  Add application Rating  Facility To the  My Application  What

Should I Do For This Thing Happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone/iPad In app rating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643275/iphone-ipad-in-app-rating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't let the user rate your app inside your app. What you could do is force him to visit the App Store and rate your app there, but I as a user hate this kind of "please rate me 5 stars for updates plox".

Comment: Is IT Possible To Rate The Application From the Application It Self. using The RSS Of THE I-tunes ? Thank You For Your Reply

Comment: OK YOU Are absolutely Right as a user

Comment: @Freezing Fire: Nope, its not possible by showing the iTunes web view as this is different to the one thats displayed in the App Store app.